# Doctrine2 - HasLifecycleCallbacks - Semantical Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

when i try to deploy my project on server and i use in CLI

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

i got this error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\prePersist" in method ... does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

this is my code:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...")
 * @ORM\Table(name="...")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User {
```

localy on my php5.4.4 WAMP everything works nice.

Any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You use somewhere:

```
/*
 * @ORM\prePersist
 */
```

instead of

```
/*
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
```

This works in your Windows because it has a case INsensitive filesystem, whereas linux systems have a case sensitive filesystem.

Comment: Can someone please help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992549/symfony2-orm-prepersist-not-working